# No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/recommenders/updates/stable/ (error)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

```
No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/recommenders/updates/stable/.
```

I've got this issue when I've tried to install `Eclipse code recommenders` , and it seems strange , I tried to add this URL to `Window/Preferences/Available Software` in side list , press realod and apply changes and tried once more , but it didn't help , this solution I've found on the internet. Does someone have any ideas?

Comment: Code Recommender was archived a while ago. Your Eclipse seems pretty outdated. Get a fresh Eclipse with a fresh workspace (or at least restore default preferences of _Java > Editor > Content Assist_ and of _... > Advanced_).

Answer (score 0):

As shown on the official Eclipse Code Recommenders web page [1] this project has been archived as it was not actively maintained anymore. Therefore I think you have to build it from source if you like to use it.

[1] https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.recommenders